# Como manipular ComboBOX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, combobox

Ola pessoal tenho 2 comboBox e tenho 1 (um) arquivo com textos e subtextos

**texto1**

<001>ola

<002>Oi

**texto2**

*<001>casa*

*<002>hospital*

....

Quero carregar essas informaçoes nos 2 combobox

Combobox1 = Texto1

Combobox2 = subtextos

ex1:

Combobox1 = Texto1

Combobox2 = <001>Ola

ex2:

Combobox1 = Texto2

Combobox2 = <001>casa

Espero que entendam e me ajudem por favor

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma lista e atribuir ela ao combobox.

```
public sealed class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public string Valor { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Texto;
    }
 }
```

Uso:

```
   var itens = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
   itens.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Valor = "1", Texto = "Ola" });
   itens.Add(new ComboBoxItem { Valor = "2", Texto = "Oi" });

   cbo.DataSource = itens;
   cbo.DisplayMember = "Texto";
   cbo.ValueMember = "Valor";
```

Resgatar valor selecionado:

```
var item = (ComboBoxItem)cbo.SelectedItem;
```